# Trying to run a query in Information Design Tool in SAP (using mssql database)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
WITH c   AS
    (SELECT A.QuestionHdrKey AS QuestionHdrKey1,
            A.DivisionKey AS DivisionKey1,
            COUNT(1) AS QCount
     FROM Mobile.QuestionLocationMap A WITH (NOLOCK)
          INNER JOIN Mobile.Question b WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.QuestionKey = b.PKey
     WHERE A.QuestionHdrKey = 200305685377000000
     GROUP BY A.QuestionHdrKey,
              A.DivisionKey),
d   AS
    (SELECT a.QuestionHdrKey,
            a.QuestionKey,
            a.DivisionKey,
            a.InvDate,
            a.HdrKey,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.DivisionKey,
                                            a.invdate,
                                            a.HdrKey
                               ORDER BY a.QuestionKey) AS RowId
     FROM mobile.StatusReport a WITH (NOLOCK)
          INNER JOIN mobile.Question b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.QuestionKey = b.PKey
                                                    AND b.QuestionType = 'rate'
                                                    AND InputType = 'numeric'
     WHERE a.QuestionHdrKey = '200305685377000000'
     GROUP BY a.QuestionHdrKey,
              a.DivisionKey,
              a.HdrKey,
              a.InvDate,
              a.QuestionKey)
SELECT a.DivisionKey,
       a.InvDate AS ModifiedDate,
       a.QuestionHdrKey,
       a.HdrKey,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.QuestionKey) AS QuestionKey,
       SUM(CAST(a.Value AS int)) AS value,
       SUM(b.Rate) AS RATE
--case when a.invdate between '2020-05-09' and '2022-03-31' then case when  then case when    cast(Value as int)*5>5 then 5 else cast(Value as int)*5  end else  cast(Value as int) end  as value,c.QCount

FROM mobile.StatusReport a WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN mobile.Question b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.QuestionKey = b.PKey
                                               AND b.QuestionType = 'rate'
                                               AND InputType = 'numeric'
     INNER JOIN c WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.DivisionKey = c.DivisionKey1
     INNER JOIN d WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.HdrKey = d.HdrKey
                               AND a.QuestionKey = d.QuestionKey
WHERE a.QuestionHdrKey = '200305685377000000'
  --and  a.HdrKey='210305757994230000'
  AND d.RowId <= c.QCount
GROUP BY a.DivisionKey,
         a.InvDate,
         a.QuestionHdrKey,
         a.HdrKey,
         c.QCount;
```

I have this table queried in PowerBI which generates the below table:

[image: example image of queried table]

The SQL is validated successfully in Information Design Tool but when trying to view its values, it shows an error in the code. How do I work around this?

Comment: Suggested reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) & [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Honestly, the fact that you use `NOLOCK` against all the objects defined in your CTEs `c` and `d` and then use `NOLOCK` against the CTEs themselves in the outer `SELECT` demonstrates you have no idea what that hint does and that you should not be using it.

Comment: "it shows an error in the code" What exactly does that mean? We can't read your mind or see your screen. If an error occurs, include the complete error message (not an image of it).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error is literally just "There was a syntax error near )".

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after figuring out that "with as" doesn't work outside of the select function in the IDS, I've ditched the aliases and used sub-queries.

```
    select HdrKey,a.DivisionKey,InvDate,RowId ,count(b.QuestionKey) as QCount,qCOUNT_,[value],POINT
from 

(select  distinct  a.HdrKey,a.DivisionKey, a.InvDate, ROW_NUMBER()   OVER(PARTITION BY QuestionHdrKey, DivisionKey, a.InvDate ORDER BY a.InvDate) AS RowId,
sum(cast([value] as int)) AS [value], COUNT(DISTINCT A.QuestionKey) AS qCOUNT_, SUM(B.Rate) AS POINT
    from NominInventory.mobile.StatusReport a with(nolock)
    inner join NominInventory.mobile.Question b with(nolock) on a.QuestionKey=b.PKey and B.QuestionType = 'rate' and InputType='numeric'
    where a.QuestionHdrKey='200305685377000000'
    GROUP BY   a.HdrKey,a.DivisionKey, a.InvDate,QuestionHdrKey
    ) a
    inner join NominInventory.Mobile.QuestionLocationMap b with(nolock) on a.DivisionKey=b.DivisionKey and b.QuestionHdrKey = '200305685377000000'

    group by HdrKey,a.DivisionKey,InvDate,RowId,qCOUNT_,[value],POINT
    having a.RowId<=count(b.QuestionKey)
```